Sending Data By Ajax But Always Null Object In Controller
I sent information using ajax but I don't understand why in the controller what I get is always null data. I went crazy and tried everything I could find on here but still no success. Please help me in this exercise, thank you very much.
Here is my model:
This is ajax code:
var data = {
    "FlightId": flightId,
    "UserId": userId,
    "Cmnd": cmnd,
    "FullName": fullName,
    "Birthday": birthday,
    "Phone": phone,
    "Email": email,
    "SeatNumber": seatNumber,
    "TransactionTime": transTime,
    "TransactionAmount": amount,
    "AircraftId": airCraftId,
    "DepartureAirportId": departureAirport,
    "ArrivalAirportId": arrivalAiport,
    "DepartureTime": departureTime,
    "ArrivalTime": arrivalTime,
    "Price": amount
};

console.log(data);

$.ajax({
    url: "https://localhost:7129/Booking/AddTicket",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify(data) ,
    success: function (response) {
        console.log("Success");
        console.log(response);
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        console.log("Fail!");
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
    }
});

And i get null in controller:
null object
